Difference in nesting left and right loops in Java expression evaluation
Basically we have string expression of numbers and operators and output has to return all possible results from computing all the different possible ways to group numbers and operators. Obtaining different results by placing operations in parentheses.
Example 1:
Input: expression = "2-1-1"
Output: [0,2]
Explanation:
((2-1)-1) = 0
(2-(1-1)) = 2
Example 2:

Input: expression = "2*3-4*5"
Output: [-34,-14,-10,-10,10]
Explanation:
(2*(3-(4*5))) = -34
((2*3)-(4*5)) = -14
((2*(3-4))*5) = -10
(2*((3-4)*5)) = -10
(((2*3)-4)*5) = 10

here is my code snippet
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> diffWaysToCompute(String expression) {
        ArrayList <Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (!expression.contains("+") && !expression.contains("-") && !expression.contains("*")) {
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(expression));            
        }
        
        for(int i=0 ; i<expression.length()-1 ; i++){
            if(expression.charAt(i) == '+' || expression.charAt(i) == '-' || expression.charAt(i) == '*'){
                String leftpart = expression.substring(0,i);
                String rightpart = expression.substring(i+1);                
                List <Integer> leftresults = diffWaysToCompute(leftpart);
                List <Integer> rightresults = diffWaysToCompute(rightpart);
                for (int left : leftresults) {
                    for (int right : rightresults) {
                        if (expression.charAt(i) == '+') {
                            result.add(left + right);
                        } else if (expression.charAt(i) == '-') {
                            result.add(left - right);
                        } else if (expression.charAt(i) == '*') {
                            result.add(left * right);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }                            
        return result;
    }
}

I didn't understand the part of right loop is nested in left loop. What happen if we try to nest left inside right? What is the differences between this two?
for (int left : leftresults) {
    for (int right : rightresults) {

for (int right : rightresults) {
    for (int left : leftresults) {


I would try both ways and see what difference it makes.

Your code takes a math expression (like "23-45") and finds all possible ways to calculate it.
How it works:

Check if the expression has any operators (+, -, *). If not, just convert it to a number.

Look at each character in the expression. If it's an operator:
Split the expression into two parts at that operator.

Recursively calculate all possible results for each part.
Combine the results from both parts using the operator (+, -, *).


The issue:
If you call right list first ,the code mixes up the order of the results from the two parts. It should pair results from the left part with results from the right part, not from the right part with results from the left part.
Example:
Expression: "23-45"
Correct pairing: (23) - (45)
Incorrect pairing: (45) - (23)
As the correct order matters , i ran the above code with order right to left -
code-
class Solution {
public List<Integer> diffWaysToCompute(String expression) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!expression.contains("+") && !expression.contains("-") && !expression.contains("*")) {
        result.add(Integer.parseInt(expression));
    }
    
    for (int i = expression.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (expression.charAt(i) == '+' || expression.charAt(i) == '-' || expression.charAt(i) == '*') {
            String leftpart = expression.substring(0, i);
            String rightpart = expression.substring(i + 1);
            List<Integer> leftresults = diffWaysToCompute(leftpart);
            List<Integer> rightresults = diffWaysToCompute(rightpart);
            for (int right : rightresults) {
                for (int left : leftresults) {
                    if (expression.charAt(i) == '+') {
                        result.add(left + right);
                    } else if (expression.charAt(i) == '-') {
                        result.add(left - right);
                    } else if (expression.charAt(i) == '*') {
                        result.add(left * right);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

}
output -
[-34, -10, 10, -14]
